# Unable to set up facebook open graph protocol for my blog

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I'm having a problem with Facebook Open Graph implementation with my wordpress blog. Although all the og meta are there in the head, Facebook debug tool told me: **Error Parsing URL : Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.** 
Things I've already done:

- Check for links mistypo
- Try the Wordpress SEO plugin by Yoast, Facebook Open Graph impementation
- Try WP Facebook Open Graph Protocol plugin
- Remove and put manualy all the og meta tags in my header file one by one to found the error

None of these tricks worked and all of them ended with [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=sfapress.uphero.com) telling me: **Error Parsing URL : Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.**
But I founded that [Google Webmaster Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://sfapress.uphero.com) can see my tags and information about my blog. If you check source at [sfapress.uphero.com](http://sfapress.uphero.com) you'll see that og meta tags are there where they are expected to be.

So, I'm just wondering: What am I missing? How wrong am I about that? Can anyone of you guys please help me figure this out? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your hosting provider, or possibly your web server, is denying access to the Facebook scraper. This is why it's saying no data was scraped. Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#bestpractices and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper for information on how the scraper appears to web servers.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll take a look and let you know about further results.

Comment: After deeper search, it's looks like Facebook banned the whole *uphero.com domain as spam site. :( So unless, I look for another subdomain, I wouldn't be able to do share links to Facebook. Thanks for help.